# Comparing array of dates with DateTimePicker to disable dates not working

Tags: android, datetimepicker

i want to disable holidays from DateTimePicker in android, and for that i have created an Array of Holidays and Comparing it with Calendar Dates inside while Loop but it is not working.

Here is My Code:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,DialogInterface.OnCancelListener{

```
private TextView textView;
private static final String[] bankHolidays = {"2017/09/25","2017/09/26","2017/09/27","2017/09/28"};
private static final java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
private static Set<java.util.Calendar> holidayDates;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_datepicker);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                schedule(v);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private int year,month,day,hour,minute;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void schedule(View v) throws ParseException {
    if (holidayDates == null) {
        holidayDates = new HashSet<java.util.Calendar>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bankHolidays.length; i++) {
            java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = sdf.parse(bankHolidays[i]);
            c.setTime(date);
            holidayDates.add(c);
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"welcome",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    intDatetimeData();
    java.util.Calendar cDefault =java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cDefault.set(year,month,day);
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=DatePickerDialog.newInstance(this,

            cDefault.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR),
            cDefault.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH),
            cDefault.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );

    java.util.Calendar cMax = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    java.util.Calendar cMin = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cMax.set(cMax.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR),11,31);
    datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(cMin);
    datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(cMax);

    List<java.util.Calendar> daylist =  new LinkedList<>();
    java.util.Calendar[] daysArray;
    java.util.Calendar cAux = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    while (cAux.getTimeInMillis() <= cMax.getTimeInMillis() )
    {
        if ( cAux.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != java.util.Calendar.SATURDAY  && !holidayDates.contains(cAux.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))){
            java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis(cAux.getTimeInMillis());
            daylist.add(c);
        }
        cAux.setTimeInMillis(cAux.getTimeInMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
    daysArray= new java.util.Calendar[daylist.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<daysArray.length;i++)
    {
       daysArray[i]=daylist.get(i);
    }

    datePickerDialog.setSelectableDays(daysArray);

    datePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
    datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePickerDialog");
}
```